# Character encoding in request.getRemoteUser()

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, request, character-encoding

Every request comes through Microsoft IIS and an AJP13 Connector to the Tomcat. Some usernames contains German special characters. If the user name is "Kloß", `request.getRemoteUser()` returns "KloÃ?". In the Tomcats localhost_access_log the user name is logged correctly as "Kloß".

How can I convert the return value of `request.getRemoteUser()` to an UTF-8 string?

I tried without success:

```
String s1 = request.getRemoteUser()
String s2 = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.newStringUtf8(request.getRemoteUser().getBytes())
```

Comment: Have you tried `new String(s1.getBytes(), "utf-8");`?

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this. The result is the same like in String s2

Comment: What is your access log encoding? I would guess it is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The access log is UTF-8. The "ß" encoded as C3 9f

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to find out, what encoding the `getRemoteUser()` yields.

On a pure UTF-8 system i executed this:

```
    String name = "Kloß";
    System.out.printf("%x%n", new BigInteger(1, name.getBytes()));
```

Which printed

```
    4b6c6fc39f
  /*K l o ß   */
```

Feeding `c39f` to the search on fileformat.info we find that it's a [LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/df/index.htm) in it's utf-8 hexadecimal representation.

So execute the above printf with your `request.getRemoteUser()` and try to find out in which charset your `ß` is. If the request is from a windows machine, I would guess its "CP1252".

Comment: Thanks! I have created a new user. The name is "äöüß". Your above code printed the following in the log: "c3a4c3b6c3bcc33f". 

c3a4 = ä, c3b6=ö, c3bc=ü. This is UTF-8. But what ist the c33f?

Comment: @PosNerd 'c33f' is not one, but actually two characters: `C3` = `Ã` and `3F` = `?`. Which means that at that time it's already too late: Someone already converted your string. You have to search farther upstream. Maybe somehow log out the output of IIS?

Comment: IIS and the AJP1.3 connector are working well. Tomcat writes the username in its own localhost_access_log correctly.  Something inside Tomcat destroys the "ß". I suppose that it is not intended to support special characters in usernames.

I have tried special characters with the tomcatAuthentication and the tomcat-users.xml. It does not work at all.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue, maybe this will help? https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7011206